# Array/List/Object to JSON Issue

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a question related to serialising list/array to JSON. This is done in a WFS and I'm using it's serialization (ie not doing any on my own)
This is the rough code of what I have:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyObject
{
  [DataMember]
  string name;
  [DataMember]
  string value;
  public MyObject(string n, string v)
  {
     name = n;
    value = v;
  }
}
```

Then I have a list of these objects:

```
List <MyObject> lst = new List <MyObject>();
lst.add(new MyObject("Surname", "Smith"));
return lst;
```

Now the resultant JSON is something like:

```
[{"name":"Surname", "value":"Smith"}]
```

What I would however like to get is:

```
[{"Surname":"Smith"}]
```

What am I doing wrong in my object definition, or elsewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use json.net from newtonsoft. It serialises in the form you want.

Comment: yes but it returns in string format which breaks things form me (ie: it inserts escape characters). I also don't really want to use that library if WCF already has serialization, would like to avoid 3rd party dependence.